# Add Values of a field specific to input value of another field

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement which is to be achieved using xslt. It requires to add only those values of field 'NETWR' under E1EDP01, when another field WERKS under E1EDP01 satisfies a certain condition. This added sum is to be populated under different node field SUMME under E1EDS01 (Occurrence of E1EDS01 is only one). Condition for WERKS is , it must have value = VK10 0r VK11 0r VK12 or (VK13 and IDTNR is not blank). I tried with below XSLT code but it gives me value '0'in output.Could anyone please help?
XSLT I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ZNUMBER>
         <IDOC>
            <xsl:for-each select="Z_MM/IDOC/E1EDS01">
               <E1EDS01>
                  <SUMME>
                     <xsl:value-of select="sum(Z_MM/IDOC/E1EDP01[(WERKS=&apos;VK13&apos; and E1EDP19/IDTNR!=&apos;&apos;) or WERKS = &apos;VK10&apos; or WERKS = &apos;VK11&apos; or WERKS = &apos;VK12&apos; ]/@NETWR)"/>
                  </SUMME>
               </E1EDS01>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </IDOC>
      </ZNUMBER>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Z_MM>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
         <NETWR>20</NETWR>
         <WERKS>VK13</WERKS>
         <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <IDTNR>000000000000211087</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
      </E1EDP01>
      <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
         <NETWR>10</NETWR>
         <WERKS>VK11</WERKS>
         <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>001</QUALF>
         </E1EDP19>
      </E1EDP01>
      <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
         <SUMID>002</SUMID>
         <SUMME></SUMME>
         <SUNIT></SUNIT>
      </E1EDS01>
   </IDOC>
</Z_MM>
```

OUTPUT should come as 20+10=30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `sum` function is within an `xsl:for-each` in which you select `E1EDS01` elements, so you expression is relative to that. In other words, it is looking for a child element of `E1EDS01` called `ZM1`. If you want to search outside the current element, precede the expression `/` to start at the document node again. Additionally your expression is currently summing `@NEWTR` which is an attribute, whereas in your XML it is an element.

Try this expression.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Z_MM/IDOC/E1EDP01[(WERKS='VK13' and E1EDP19/IDTNR!='') or WERKS = 'VK10' or WERKS = 'VK11' or WERKS = 'VK12']/NETWR)"/>
```

Having said that, looking at your current XSLT, you don't really need the `xsl:for-each` at all in this case, as you say there is only one `E1EDS01` and you are not actually using any value in it anyway.

Try this XSLT (The `/` is not needed here now, because you would already be positioned on the document node).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ZNUMBER>
         <IDOC>
           <E1EDS01>
              <SUMME>
                 <xsl:value-of select="sum(Z_MM/IDOC/E1EDP01[(WERKS='VK13' and E1EDP19/IDTNR!='') or WERKS = 'VK10' or WERKS = 'VK11' or WERKS = 'VK12']/NETWR)"/>
              </SUMME>
           </E1EDS01>
         </IDOC>
      </ZNUMBER>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if you XSLT is a sample, and you actually just want to populate the existing `SUMME`, you could do this with the identity template, and an extra template to match `SUMME`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="SUMME">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(/Z_MM/IDOC/E1EDP01[(WERKS='VK13' and E1EDP19/IDTNR!='') or WERKS = 'VK10' or WERKS = 'VK11' or WERKS = 'VK12']/NETWR)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the response. I have tried with both the approach, but still not in receipt of correct output. When tried with first approach  <E1EDS01>
              <SUMME>
                 <xsl:value-of select="sum(Z_MM/IDOC/E1EDP01[(WERKS='VK13' and E1EDP19/IDTNR!='') or WERKS = 'VK10' or WERKS = 'VK11' or WERKS = 'VK12']/NETWR)"/>
              </SUMME>
           </E1EDS01> I am getting output as '0' and when tried with template appraoch, output is blank. Any further suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried both my solutions at http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfs and http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYiu and both set the `SUMME` to 30, as required. Is your input XML accurate? If you are using different XML to the question, there could be an issue if your real XML had namespaces, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution given by you has resolved the problem, though I tried in similar manner , unfortunately could not locate the exact error why it did not work earlier. Thanks.
Best Regards